# Doubts on SELECT of Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am reading some Hive QL script and found this line:
    SELECT 'Start time:',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());

What does it mean? It does not look like a real "select" statement?

Comment: what are column names in your table?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi, not relevant. No table is being queried here.

Comment: This SQL sentence can be replaced with `select current_timestamp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not query to DB. This is simply a Print statement. 
If we run the command : `SELECT 'Start time:',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());`

Out put would be :

```
Col1: Start time:
Col2: 2017-08-29 01:36:11
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[HIVE-178](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-178)   *SELECT without FROM should assume a one-row table with no columns*

> ... People use this all the time with SQL Server. I expect people to
>   like it if it is added to Hive ...
>
> ... The Hive Language Manual now states, *"As of Hive 0.13.0, FROM is
>   optional (for example, SELECT 1+1)."*

Nothing really new -- that syntax was introduced by Sybase Transact-SQL 30 years ago, before they sold their "SQL Server" code base (and product name) to Microsoft, and long before they sold the rest to SAP.

The alternate syntax uses a `DUAL` (Oracle) or `SYSDUMMY1` (DB2) pseudo-table.

Comment: Note that this syntax is useful in two cases: if you want to "print" some arbitrary message to the console *(like in your example)*; or if you want to inject some arbitrary data in a query *(e.g. unit tests)*

Comment: What does it exactly mean? In my case, "SELECT 'Start time:',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());", will it query DB? Will it be written to DB?

Comment: Read again my comment above -- especially the part that says _"like in your example"_. Also, open the link to the Hive JIRA and read it. Last but not least, think about what SELECT means in English. Somewhat akin to to GET, right?

Comment: Recommended readings: a tutorial about SQL (with some comparison of various dialects); an good intro to the relational model (i.e. not the Wikipedia page)